# c++ create an array with string::size

Tags: c++, arrays

Im trying to create an array with the string::size member but its complaining at the declaration of "char message[msgSize]" that the expression did not evalute to a constant.

However it alows me to declare "msgSize".

How can this be? Why am i allowed to make a constant but i'm not allowed to use it to something that needs a const.

If the answer is that: "the size of the string could change" then the same argument can be made for using sizeof(), but that works.

```
const unsigned int msgSize = 
        saveAs.size() +
        sizeof("NOTE|  sent get request to: ") + 10;

    char message[msgSize];
    memset(message, 0, msgSize);
    sprintf_s(message, msgSize,"NOTE| sent get request to: %s", saveAs.c_str());
    _cRec->output(message);
```

Comment: `sizeof` can be evaluated at compile time while `string.size()` cannot.

Comment: There's an important difference between a `const` variable and a constant expression.

Comment: `const` is not `constexpr`. If your compiler can figure a `const` is a constant expression, as with the `sizeof`, it might let you use it as a `constexpr` variable, but not if you throw in a runtime-only expression such as `saveAs.size()`

Comment: Perhaps a `std::vector` might help you? Or something like: `string message("NOTE| sent get request to: "); message.append(saveAs); _cRec->output(message.c_str());` (assuming `_cRec->output()` doesn't modify the passed in string).

Comment: Since you're using C++, a `std::string` would be much more appropriate here.

Comment: Or if you want to get a little code-golfy: `_cRec->output(string("NOTE| sent get request to: ").append(saveAs).c_str());`

Comment: My point is that manually managing string buffer sizes is where bugs live - let the C++ `string` class deal with that crap to the maximum extent possible.  For example, why did you add `10` to `msgSize`?  Just to make extra sure that there was enough space for the message? Or does `output() actually write past the end of the passed in string?

Comment: added 10 to make sure it would be null terminated. Since for somereason it returns a wrong value on really long strings. Actually i have no idea why i didnt just use a regular string.

Comment: "for some reason it returns a wrong value on really long strings": I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "it" (`saveAs.size()` or `sizeof()` or ???) but that sounds very weird. You might consider posting a question specifically about that problem.

Comment: I cant remember which it was. I solved it. I shouldn't say "it returns wrong value" i guess. Since it's returning the value it should haha. Altho i'm after another value, i just got the two functions mixed up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well `const` just means that you promise that the value won't change. And you can even override that with a `const_cast`.

What compiler needs there is a value that can be evaluated at the compile time. This is a stronger requirement. Such values are marked with `constexpr` keyword.

Unfortunately you are out of luck with `std::string`... `size()` is not a `constexpr`.

I played with the [`following example`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dac243b31b7d5cd6):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

const string msg("Some msg");
constexpr int msg_len = msg.size();

int main() {

    char msg[msg_len];

    cout << sizeof(msg);
    return 0;
}
```

The thing is that `size()` is not a `constexpr`, and you cannot make `string` a `constexpr` because it has a non-trivial destructor.

Why it is designed this way is beyond me. Seems like a counter intuitive and serious limitation. However, there are pretty clever implementation of `string`, for example with small storage optimization. It might be hard to make them `constexpr` with out serious changes in the implementation.

Comment: _"Why it is designed this way is beyond me."_ How could `std::string` possibly be `constexpr` when it involves dynamic allocation at runtime?

Comment: Have you read following sentences? There are more implementations, so your statement is not universally true. The question is about design. You give technical detail which is a consequence. Maybe c++ is lacking const-string type?

Comment: There are not "more implementations"; SSO exists but it is not possible at compile-time to know whether it will be sufficient or whether further resizing will be required. Supporting that requires either dynamic allocation, or infinite statically-allocated space. As for a const-string type, I'd like to see that; perhaps some thin-ish wrapper around a `char[n]`. It would be very limited, though.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to make your array dynamic.
The size of the string is not known at *compile* time, but only at run time.

Also, your listing is not a minimal compilable example. I can only assume `saveAs` is an std::string.

The following would work:

```
int main()
   {
        std::string myString("My string");
        char * myCStyleString = new char[myString.size()];

        delete[] myCStyleString;
   }
```

because we are *dynamically* allocating an array there.

What are you trying to do? It looks like you just want to copy a filename into a message string. Just keep using std::string;

```
   int main()
   {
        std::string myString("My string");
        std::string message = "I like beans and rice with: ";
        message += myString;

        return 0;
   }
```

but again, I'd need a minimal compilable example to determine your goal.

Answer (score 0):

> Why am i allowed to make a constant but i'm not allowed to use it to
>   something that needs a const.

This is because the "constant" expression you have is made up of non constant parts i.e. the size method of the string class. It is not truly constant in terms of having a known value at compile time.

Consider using `constexpr` variable/function in the future

> If the answer is that: "the size of the string could change" then the
>   same argument can be made for using sizeof(), but that works.

No that same argument cannot be used for sizeof because sizeof does not need it's arguement to be a constant.

---

If you know for a fact that `saveAs` contains a string with a known size, then perhaps it would be best if you declare that size as a constant and then refer to it in your calculation:

```
constexpr unsigned int msgSize = 
        SAVEAS_SIZE +
        sizeof("NOTE|  sent get request to: ") + 10;
```

Then this will allow you to do:

```
char message[msgSize];
```

Answer (score 0):

In C++ you cannot declare [VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array)s.

When you declare an array, for example:

```
char message[x];
```

The expression `x` must to be valuable at [compile time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compile_time), that is its value has to be well-known when the source is compiled.

In you example:

```
char message[msgSize];
```

The expression (variable) `msgSize` is not known at compile time, but only at run time. That because the compiler has to know how many bytes reserve in the stack.

Note: the variable `msgSize` is a *constant* value. A constant value is *not* an expression evaluate at compile time. It simply means that its value cannot change once has been assigned.

In C++11 has been introduced the keywork `constexpr` in order to define an expression which should be evaluate at compile time.

However in your case there is not way to get the size of a dynamic string at compile time. So what you have to do is use dynamic array (dynamic memory).

```
char* message = new char[msgSize];
// now you have an array of msgSize lenght
// ... do stuff...
// do not forget to release the memory when end
delete[] message;
```

Finally, I suggest you to re-elaborate your code because it's likely you don't need a dynamic array of chars, but just a `std::string`. Indeed you can use overloaded operator `+` in order to concatenate strings and the method `std::string::c_str()` to access as `const char*` for backward compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

You need a **compile-time constant** with `char message[msgSize];` because this is a local variable which uses **static memory that is allocated in the data segment**, so the compiler needs to calculate the number of bytes required by the code, including the local variables and arrays.

You can use dynamic memory to solve your problem. **The dynamic memory is allocated in the heap**.  In C, you should use `malloc()`.  In C++, you should use `new[]` (or better, `std::vector`, or even `std::string`).  Then you can specify the memory size using a runtime value in a variable.

So, your code would look more like the follow:

```
char* message = new char[msgSize]; //Allocated memory
//Do everything that you need...
delete[] message; //Release memory
```

Or:

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<char> message(msgSize); //Allocated memory
//Do everything that you need...
```